# how to execute a single api which is parameterized multiple iteration in a postman collection?

Tags: postman

i have a group of  api's in postman in collection and execute in collection runner multiple times using a csv or json file and configuring iterations to required number upto this is ok. but my requirement is to run only selected apis to iterate which are parameterized not all  api's .Every time it is executing full collection suite is there any option to configure it.

please help me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand clearly but if what you want is to execute only some selected requests among your collection, you may use the setNextRequest feature (refer to http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/). It may help you as you can specify which request to play under certain conditions.

```
if (selection condition == true)
    setNextRequest(request_i_want)
```

That would allow you to 'jump' to the requests that fulfill your selection requirement.

hope this helps

Alexandre